# When should I disrupt an opponent's recall?

Tags: league-of-legends

In League of Legends, I can interrupt an opponent's recall by damaging them with a spell or autoattack, but what I'm not sure of is when it's appropriate to disrupt them.

For example, if my lane opponent is recalling and I can easily disrupt him, should I do so and keep harassing him or let him go to buy items in return for some uninterrupted CS? Or if the enemy jungler is recalling in a warded bush, should I interrupt him to keep tabs on where he is?

Comment: Be careful of the recall bait.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer to this is really simple, ask yourself the following question :
"Do I get a benefit from interrupting him ?"
- if yes do it !
- else don't !

For your lane opponent, if he just hard pushed the lane and you see him back, prevent him from doing it ! Because if he does recall, he'll barely lose any cs so make him lose time for you to prepare the push for when he is gone.

Other case, if he wants to recall because he is out of sustain (pots, flask, low health) or because he is behind in items and need to shop, PREVENT THE RECALL. You have an advantage on the lane, don't let it go.

If he is too far, and you need to overextend or lose cs, ask yourself the same question again, does it still gives you a benefit to do it ?

And for the jungler, if he is backing on a ward he doesn't know about, it might not be a good thing to prevent the recall and give the information that it is warded there, because when he comes back to your lane, he will know what to avoid. But if he is doing a stupid back in a visible place, go for it.

Comment: For the jungler, by the time he gets back there, the ward might be gone, it might be better to make him think it is always warded than not. I rather slow the jungler down as much as possible.

Comment: The ward might be gone, but when a ward is down you put another one if you do your job as support. And if he thinks the place where he recalled isn't always warded, he will certainly come by this path next time, and you'll have the upper hand by having more information than him. But well this point is too much dependant on the league you play in and personnal interpretation.

Answer (score 0):

For tactical reasons: Don't disrupt the Jungler. If he doesn't know you know where he is and where the wards are, you have the upper hand.

However, you see an opponent in-lane, open fire. That's a very big generalization, because there are a lot of tactics and different situations you might need to take into account.

LoL is very much a Mind-Game as much as anything else.

Comment: If you're winning trades in lane: disrupt. If you're having trouble let them b, force to tower so they lose xp/gold and try to get back to lane before they force it back.

Comment: I think LoL chat format took over a bit there haha.

Comment: I've been playing so long that the jargon just slips into my every day vocabulary lol

Comment: I would rather slow the jungler than not. Knowing a bush *was* warded doesn't mean it will stay like that. Even better to let the jungler wonder `Is that place still warded?`.